# Multiple Aliases for different commands

Tags: bash, unix, redhat

I am attempting to create a bash script that will ssh into remote network devices, run commands based on the model, and then save the output.

At this time I have my expect file that contains the following:

```
#!/user/bin/expect

set pw xxxxxxx
set timeout 5

spawn ssh [lindex $argv 0]

expect "TACACS Password:"
    send "$pw\r"
interact
```

I have my .sh file that contains variables which allows me to login to separate "host" files based on Model type. It contains:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases

fpath="path where scripts are located"
opath="MAC_Results.log"

for i in $( cat $fpath/3560hosts )
do
expect script.exp $i >> "$opath"
done
```

When I run my .sh, everything operates as expected. My issue lies in I do not know how to call my aliases. I have edited the .bashrc and have sourced it. The .bashrc contains the following:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions

alias loc3560="term length 0; show mac address-table | ex Gi|CPU|Po; exit"
alias locx="term length 0; show mac address-table | ex Gi[1|2]/1|CPU|Vl99|Po1|dynamic|system; exit"
```

I have also added the aliases within my .sh aliases. but cant seem to get the right syntax. I have tried the following variations but with no success...

```
for i in $( cat $fpath/3560hosts )
do
expect script.exp $i $loc3560 >> "$opath"
done
```

and

```
for i in $( cat $fpath/3560hosts )
do
expect script.exp $i >> "$opath";
$loc3560
done
```

Would appreciate any suggestions on where to put these to call to them.

Comment: Use a function instead of an alias

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will have to give this a try come Monday since everything is at work.

Comment: @Inian I have edited the bashrc file and made my commands into functions. I have sourced it again and have edited my .sh file. When I run my .sh I usually get "Command Not found" and then it has the string with my commands that I want run on the Cisco device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I was not able to figure out how to call my functions or aliases within my main .sh script. With that though I found a way to achieve what I wanted via my expect file . Code listed below and it works like a charm. My subdirectory of 21 files has now been reduced to 3!

```
set loc3560 "show mac address-table | ex Gi|CPU|Po
exit"
set locx "show mac address-table | ex Gi1/1|Gi2/1|CPU|Vl99|Po1|dynamic|system
exit"
set loc4500 "show mac address-table | ex 1/3|1/5|Port-channel|Switch|1/1|1/2|dynamic|system
exit"
set loc888 "show mac-address-table | i FastEthernet
exit"
set loces2 "show mac address-table | i Fa0
exit"

spawn ssh [lindex $argv 0]

expect "TACACS Password:"
    send "$pw\r"

expect  "#"
    send "$ver\r"

expect {
    "C3560-IPSERVICESK9-M" {
    send "$loc3560\r"
    exp_continue
}
    "CAT3K_CAA-UNIVERSALK9" {
    send "$locx\r"
    exp_continue
}
    "C3750E-UNIVERSALK9-M" {
    send "$locx\r"
    exp_continue
}
    "CISCO888-SEC-K9" {
    send "$loc888\r"
    exp_continue
}
    "bootflash:/cat4500e" {
    send "$loc4500\r"
    exp_continue
}
    "SM-ES2-24" {
    send "$loces2\r"
    exp_continue
}
}
interact

expect "#"
    send "exit\r"
end
```

From here I am then able to call my script and output it to a log file in my directory via:

```
./script.sh >> Results.log
```